# setting initial summary of the preferences on Android 3.0+

Tags: android, settings, android-preferences

In the next code there is two `findpreference(key)`, the first is in `onCreate()` and it returns null, but the second returns the preference correctly. I need the first to work well for initialize the preference summary. I've spent a lot of time trying different ways, and reading documentation and googling but I haven´t found the way, please help.

```
public class Settings30Activity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    protected SettingsFragment settingsFragment;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(11)
    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);            
       }            
     }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();    

   //findPreference 1 (returns null):        
       Preference stylePref=settingsFragment.findPreference("pref_style"); 
       stylePref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));

    }

   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {     
    if (key.equals("pref_style")) {
    //findPreference 2(returns the preference ok):
        Preference stylePref=settingsFragment.findPreference("pref_style");
        stylePref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));            
    }
}
```

}

While debugging, I can see in the variables how the the object settingsFragment/mPreferenceManager is null along the activity life cycle, until `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` is just invoked then settingsFragment/mPreferenceManager/mSharedPreferences gets sharedPrefereces and `findpreference()` works well. But I don´t know how to do for it works outside `onSharedPreferenceChanged()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns `null` because your `key` is `null` in your first `findPreference(key)` call.

In the second call, `key` is passed as a parameter to `onSharedPreferenceChanged()`, that's why it works there.

As you're looking for a key named "pref_style", you may define that name for your whole class (e.g. `static final String PREF_STYLE_KEY = "pref_style"`) and then call `findPreference(PREF_STYLE_KEY)` in your first call and `key.equals(PREF_STYLE_KEY)` in your `if()` statement.

Comment: Sorry, in my code I was looking directly for "pref_style" instead key in both cases, so that is not the thing. Thank you for your answer! While debbuging, I can see in the variables how the the object settingsFragment/mPreferenceManager is null along the activity life cycle, until onSharedPreferenceChanged() is just invoked then settingsFragment/mPreferenceManager/mSharedPreferences gets sharedPrefereces and findpreference() works well. But I don´t know how to do for it works outside onSharedPreferenceChanged().

Comment: that's strange since `mPreferenceManager` is initialized in a `PreferenceFragment`'s `onCreate()` method. Did you try to initially set the summary in the `onCreate()` of `settingsFragment` (and then debug)? BTW where do the `sharedPreferences` right after your first call come from?

Comment: Yes! Setting sumaries in the onCreate() of settingsFragment instead in the onCreate() of the Activity is the solution. Now works perfect! Thank you saschoar!

Answer (score 1):

Here´s my final code in case anyone else needs it, it works well:

```
public class Settings30Activity extends PreferenceActivity implements 
    On SharedPreferenceChangeListener {

     protected SettingsFragment settingsFragment;    


 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @TargetApi(11)
 public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);          
        setSummaries();
    }        

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void setSummaries(){
        final SharedPreferences sh = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences() ;

        //Pref1
        Preference stylePref = findPreference("pref_style");
        stylePref.setSummary(sh.getString("pref_style", ""));

        //here the other preferences..
     }  
}//End fragment

 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment(); 
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, settingsFragment)
            .commit();
 }

 public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {       

    if (key.equals("pref_style")) {
        Preference pref = settingsFragment.findPreference(key);
        // Set summary to be the user-description for the selected value
        pref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));            
    }
    //here the others preferences
  }
}
```